# VScode, LiveServer страница улетает вверх после изменений

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

VS code верстаю страницу (html, css) используя live server и когда я вношу изменение страница улетает вверх(верхней границы браз. ), как исправить?

Это не всегда происходит. Иногда все норм, внес изменение, в браузере они произошли, страница на месте, а иногда страница поднимается вверх и приходится скролить опять к месту вверстке .

Answer (score 4):

Вот что нашел может кому пригодится

VSCode Live Server: Disable scroll up on save

При использовании расширения Live Server для VS Code, замечали одну неприятную особенность.

Когда вы вносите изменения в код и сохраняетесь, страница прокручивается в начало. И если вы работали с блоками где-то посередине вам приходится каждый раз возвращаться к ним снова. Это неудобно если нужно сделать какие-то мелкие правки и до/после необходимо видеть сразу же.

Чтобы изменить это поведение, перейдите в
`File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`

В списке `Commonly Used` выберете
`Extensions` > `Live Server Config`
Найдите пункт Settings: `Full Reload` и поставьте галочку ☑

Перезагрузите VS Code и вуаля. Страница перезагружается оставаясь на том же месте с которым вы работаете в данный момент.

Альтернативные способы
Через поиск:
Открыть настройки через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (запятая в англиской раскладке)

Ввести в поиск: `liveServer.settings.fullReload`

Поставить галочку ☑
Перезагрузить VS Code.

Через settings.json:
В файле настроек редактора settings.json между фигурными скобками вставить:

```json
"liveServer.settings.fullReload": true,
```

Не забудьте запятую в конце предыдущего правила и текущего на всякий случай ;)

http://fadmin.ru/vopros/kak-otklyuchit-avtomaticheskuyu-prokrutku-v-vscode-live-server